# Power law is Nested in Power Law with Cutoff?

Tags: power-law

I'm reading "Power-Law Distributions in Empirical Data": https://arxiv.org/pdf/0706.1062.pdf.

The authors make the claim that "In some cases the distributions we wish to compare
may be nested, meaning that one family of distributions is a subset of the other. ***The
power law and the power law with exponential cutoff in Table 2.1 provide an example
of such nested distributions."***

If you were to write just the "kernels" of the pdfs for the corresponding distributions, this seems obvious:

$$ f(x) \propto x^{-\alpha}e^{-\lambda x} \ \ \text{   power law with cutoff}$$

and 
$$ g(x)\propto x^{-\alpha}  \ \ \text{power law} .$$

Sure, sure, if we let $\lambda = 0$, then $f(x)$ seems to equal $g(x)$.  But let's look at the full pdfs,

$$ f(x) = \frac{\lambda^{1-\alpha}}{\Gamma(1-\alpha, \lambda x_{min})}x^{-\alpha}e^{-\lambda x} \ \ \text{   power law with cutoff}$$

and 
$$ g(x)= (\alpha-1)x_{min}^{\alpha -1 }x^{-\alpha}  \ \ \text{power law} .$$

where $\alpha > 1$ and $x \ge x_{min} >0$.

Now it's not so obvious.  If we plug in $\lambda = 0$, then $f(x) = 0$.

In what sense can we say that these are nested?  I am not satisfied with saying "but the normalizer doesn't matter" because, as far as the equivalence of the functions is concerned, it seems to matter a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As you correctly noted, the authors of this publication refer to the cases where $\alpha > 1$. With this in mind, we arrive at the following observations:

1. When $\lambda = 0$, we divide by zero and get an indeterminate result.
2. When $\lambda \rightarrow 0$, we get $f(x) \rightarrow g(x)$.

We can show this with simple asymptotic considerations:

For $\lambda \rightarrow 0$ we get $e^{- \lambda x} \rightarrow 1$ ($x > 0$) and $\lambda ^{1-\alpha} \rightarrow \infty $ as well as $ \Gamma\left(1-\alpha,\lambda x_{min}\right) \rightarrow \infty $.

BUT: 
$$\frac{\lambda ^{1-\alpha}}{\Gamma\left(1-\alpha,\lambda x_{min}\right)} \rightarrow \frac{\alpha - 1}{x_{min}} \left(\frac{1}{x_{min}}\right)^{-\alpha} \text{, for }\lambda \rightarrow 0$$
The reason for the latter is the asymptotic behavior of the upper incomplete gamma function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Asymptotic_behavior):
$$ \frac{\Gamma\left(1-\alpha,\lambda x_{min}\right)}{(\lambda x_{min})^{1-\alpha}} \rightarrow -\frac{1}{1-\alpha} , $$ therefore

$$\frac{\lambda ^{1-\alpha}}{\Gamma\left(1-\alpha,\lambda x_{min}\right)} = \left(\frac{\Gamma\left(1-\alpha,\lambda x_{min}\right)}{(\lambda x_{min})^{1-\alpha}} (x_{min})^{1-\alpha}\right)^{-1}\rightarrow  \frac{-(1-\alpha)}{x_{min}^{1-\alpha}} =\frac{\alpha - 1}{x_{min}} \left(\frac{1}{x_{min}}\right)^{-\alpha}. $$

In this sense, power law and power law with exponential cutoff are nested distributions as you can derive the former from the latter for $\lambda \rightarrow 0$.

In addition, the log-log plot below shows how the power law with cutoff asymptotically approaches the power law in the arbitrary case of $x = 1$, $\alpha = 2.5$, $x_{min} = 0.1$ and $\lambda = 10^{-m}$.
[image]